# Extjs Date picker display issue

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, datepicker

I wrote code of ExtJS for date picker, and include it in two different HTML file. Height of text box is different in the first HTML file than in the other. My code is :

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    height: '15%',
    width: $("#MainWindow_Right_Panel").width() - 20,
    renderTo: 'FilterControl',
    id: 'DatePicker_Panel',
    border: 0,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'To',
            name: 'to_date',
            style: 'float: right',
            id: 'todate',
            padding: 5,
            width: 130,
            labelWidth: 30,
            value: todate,
            maxValue: today,
            format: "d.m.Y",
            layout: 'form',
            listeners: {
                select: function(combo, value) {
                     todate=value;

                }
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'From',
            style: 'float: right',
            labelWidth: 50,
            width: 150,
            name: '_fromdate',
            padding: 5,
            id: 'fromdate',
            value:fromdate,
            maxValue: today,
            format: "d.m.Y",
            layout: 'form',
            listeners: {
                select: function(combo, value) {
                   fromdate=value;
                }
            }

        },
    ]
});
```

output in first HTML:

[image]

in the second:

[image]

Comment: this type of issue occur when the ids are same .please tell me your both html contain same code.

Comment: this is common control and included in two different file, i already try with unique id, so i don't this it is issue of id.

i try answer of limitall and it is working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add cls:'x-border-box, x-border-box',

after add cls you code should be like this :

```
 Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    height: '15%',
    width: $("#MainWindow_Right_Panel").width() - 20,
    renderTo: 'FilterControl',
    id: 'DatePicker_Panel',
    border: 0,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'To',
            name: 'to_date',
            style: 'float: right',
            **cls:'x-border-box, x-border-box',**
            id: 'todate',
            padding: 5,
            width: 130,
            labelWidth: 30,
            value: todate,
            maxValue: today,
            format: "d.m.Y",
            layout: 'form',
            listeners: {
                select: function(combo, value) {
                     todate=value;

                }
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'From',
            style: 'float: right',
            **cls:'x-border-box, x-border-box',**
            labelWidth: 50,
            width: 150,
            name: '_fromdate',
            padding: 5,
            id: 'fromdate',
            value:fromdate,
            maxValue: today,
            format: "d.m.Y",
            layout: 'form',
            listeners: {
                select: function(combo, value) {
                   fromdate=value;
                }
            }

        },
    ]
});
```